# jQuery scroll content at specific class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

I am using [mCustomScrollbar](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Custom-Scrollbar-Plugin-malihu/) script for custom scroll bar effect now I want to scroll page on specific class element. Class position is not fixed, It can be `top` or `bottom`.

In my example I have one anchor link and I want to page scroll to `active` class. Page will  scroll only when user `click` to anchor.

Here is my JS Code:

```
$( "#scroll" ).click(function() {
    //scroll page to active class
});

$("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
    scrollButtons: {
        enable: true
    }
});
```

Here is my JSFiddle:  http://goo.gl/6dpT7l

**Note: Scroll position is not fixed. It can be anywhere UP/Down.**

Any Idea? How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: @Harko I have tried but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle, it seems to be as simple as scrolling to the paragraph in question's position().top attribute. Replace your alert with this:

```
$("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar('scrollTo', $('.active').position().top);
```